# Get last set bit position for an int

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

Is there a fast way to get the last bit of an integer in Java. Can be both the bit at position 5 or an integer with only the 5'th bit.

```
65 -> 64 
11 -> 8 
13 -> 8
```

No negative numbers

---

It's a wording issue it's not the last bit but highest bit.

Comment: the last bit of an integer is the 8th...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dive in the javadoc, always worth it: [Integer.highestOneBit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#highestOneBit-int-).

```
assert 64 == Integer.highestOneBit(65);
assert 2 == Integer.bitCount(65);
assert 6 == 31 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(65);
```

There is also `numberOfTrailingZeros` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Integer.toBinaryString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString(int)) method, which will give you a string representation of the integer argument as an unsigned integer in base 2.

```
String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(value);
char lastBit = binary.charAt(0);
```

Comment: That's useless. It'll be the character '1' for everything except zero.